# Pivot spark multilevel Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the `Dataset` in Spark with these schemas:

```
root
 |-- from: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v1: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v2: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v3: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags: string (nullable = true)
 |-- to: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags: string (nullable = true)
```

How to make the table(with only 3 columns id,name,tags) from this Dataset on Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just combine all the columns into an `array`, `explode` and select all nested fields:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array, col, explode}

case class Vertex(id: String, name: String, tags: String)

val df  = Seq(((
  Vertex("1", "from", "a"), Vertex("2", "V1", "b"), Vertex("3", "V2", "c"), 
  Vertex("4", "v3", "d"), Vertex("5", "to", "e")
)).toDF("from", "v1", "v2", "v3", "to")


df.select(explode(array(df.columns map col: _*)).alias("col")).select("col.*")
```

with the result as follows:

```
+---+----+----+
| id|name|tags|
+---+----+----+
|  1|from|   a|
|  2|  V1|   b|
|  3|  V2|   c|
|  4|  v3|   d|
|  5|  to|   e|
+---+----+----+
```